# Python pandas issues with .drop and a non-unique index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame, say `df`, and I'm trying to drop certain rows by an index. Specifically:

```
myindex = df[df.column2 != myvalue].index
df.drop(myindex, inplace = True)
```

This seems to work just fine for most DataFrames but strange things seem to happen with one DataFrame where I get a non-unique index `myindex` (I am not quite sure why since the DataFrame has no duplicate rows). To be more precise, a lot more values get dropped than there are in the index (in the extreme case I actually drop all rows even though there are several hundred rows where `column2` has `myvalue`). Extracting only unique values (`myindex.unique()` and dropping the rows using the unique index doesn't help either. At the same time,

```
df = df[df.column2 != myvalue]
```

works just as I'd like it to. I'd rather use the inplace drop however but more importantly I would like to understand why the results are not the same with the direct asignment and with the drop method using the index.

Unfortunately, I cannot provide the data as those cannot be published and since I am not sure what is wrong exactly, I cannot simulate them either. However, I suspect it probably has something to do with `myindex` being nonunique (which also confuses me since there are no duplicate rows in `df` but it might very well be that I misunderstand the way the index is created).

Comment: If you can provide an example dataframe and alsof provide expected output, we can help you better.

Comment: Do `df = df[df.column2 == myvalue]`. Don't use the index here; the index is duplicated and thus not directly related to the dropping condition.

Comment: @ALollz: The reason I want to use drop is that these DataFrames are attributes of an object. I could of course do it like this and then use setattr(). I'm not sure whether that is preferable to restarting the index as ecortazar suggested in his answer and using an inplace drop.

Comment: @Trademark In that case then you probably should reset the index. If you aren't sure why it's duplicated, then chances are it's not actually something you care about anyway, so just give it a new one. If I had to guess, it's duplicated as the result of an `append` or `concat`, and if that's the case you can fix that further up in your code by adding `ignore_index=True` as an argument to those methods.

Comment: @ALollz: Your guess is probably right, I do concatenate several csv files to create the DataFrame (on the other hand, I also do it with other DataFrames which don't have this issue). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are repeated values in your index, doing reset_index before might help. That will set your current index as a column and add a new sequential index (with unique values) instead.

```
df = df.reset_index()
```

The reason the 2 methods are not the same is that in one case you are passing a series of booleans that represents with rows to keep and which ones to drop (index values are not relevant here). In the case with the drop, you are passing a list of index values (which map to several positions).

Finally, to check is your index has duplicates, you shouldn't check for duplicate rows. Simply do:

```
df.index.has_duplicates
```

Comment: Great, that seems to have fixed it! I am still not sure how one can get a nonunique index when there are no duplicate rows in a DataFrame. Could you please explain that to me?

Comment: having duplicate rows and having duplicate indices are different things. You should make sure to be testing for the right thing. I've edited my response.

Comment: How can you get duplicate indices then? I know it is probably hard to answer without seeing the data but I only load it from a csv file, clean the DataFrame by removing a few columns and duplicate rows and then I add another column whose values are based on the values of two other columns. Where can I acquire the nonunique index in this process? Sorry if this is too vague for a meaningful answer.

EDIT: Alollz suggests in a comment that this might occur when I concatenate the csv files during loading.

Comment: When reading from the CSV (or after) are you setting a particular column as the index? If so, that column might of had duplicates before becoming the index. EDIT: If you are concatenating several df's, you might want to add ignore_index=True in the concatenation, so that it resets the index as you concatenate

Comment: I have a weird on for this. I need to make 4 columns into datetime. 1 column(series) works just fine. The other 3 give me the InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects. When i tried the above to check for index duplicates it says false as there are none. If I reset index I still get the same error. This is my first time seeing something like this.